# Reduce height of cesium map container

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm using cesium map 3D i want to reduce its size but it is not getting reduced

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
    width: 100%; height: 60%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

I'm trying to give height 60% but this is not working.

[Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=bY7BasMwDIZfRfjUQrDZtXXDoNfBDoOefFETdROT7WIrKd3Yuy9Jdxhbdfs/fb/QiAVGpgsV2EGiC+yp8hDtYWGrYLol73NS5EQlmAY+QwoJE0dUzmkDJ5RKzQyVI8mk/bAZfa23pjG+6lWoDQmWeeR4zkVhKLKy1inFs6BSdceheye1Xa3r7U327nfV9zwC97s7f0EnWOu0OQ0iL/xBwbTeTf6/qmTsOb0+j1QEr7P29tA+3aC11rsp3m9qznLE8ufyNw)
Any suggestions Please, Thanks

Comment: `60%` of what, screen height?

Comment: @AlanOmar: I have added sand castle link also i want to reduce the height of map suppose it is 100% i want to make it 60%

Comment: what happen if you put `#cesiumContainer` in its own css rule meaning: #cesiumContainer {
    width: 100%; height: 60%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

Comment: @AlanOmar: Map doesn't displays you can try it in sandcastle, i have added the link

Comment: how do i access the css file?

Comment: I've tried your code and it runs perfectly when zoom in or zoom out map .

Comment: @JeffriAndriyanto: but i want to reduce the height of map div

Comment: @AlanOmar: You can check there is html file

Comment: adding style="height:60%;" to the <div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize" ></div> seems to shrink its size is this what you want?

Comment: @AlanOmar: Yes it should shrink without disturbing globe

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "!important" statement in your CSS.
Here's [Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=bY/BasMwEER/ZatSSMBI7aWHxA6FXAs5FHrSRbE38VJZMtLaiVv675XtFEoa3fbtzOyoNwF6whMGKMDhCbYYqWvk+8QWWpTTvPWODTkMWmTwpZ12xlFjmLxbwcHYiNkImRq0SXZhI/perkUm8siDxY12ML0XalofGLpgF1Iqxqa1hjGqfVd+IMsyxuV6Fufq16rdnAI8tFhowXhmlZRapOX9Vc+x5GivkY41r+D58QHu5qvG8SU7tUuh6m+3vKIeqCpufBxKa2JMm0Nn7Rt9Yjqcq6T/Z7XeVOSOux6DNcMoq582rzOUUuYqjbed7L3dm3CV/AM).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the Cesium container size directly in the html `div` like so:

```
<body>
  <div id='map' style='width: 700px; height: 500px;'></div>
  <script>
      // your .js code goes here
  </script>
</body>
```

I use pixels as my size units, but you can replace with % if desired.